# VBA: Pass in and return an array in a function

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to be able to pass in an array, do something with the values in it, and then return a resulting array in a function.

Is there another way to do this without using Variant?

I know this doesn't work but I want it to look something like this: (assuming arr and Test() are the same lengths)

```
Function Test()(arr() As Integer) As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Test(i) = arr(i) + 1
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Function AddOne(arr() As Integer) As Integer()
    Dim i, rv() As Integer
    ReDim rv(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        rv(i) = arr(i) + 1
    Next i
    AddOne = rv()
End Function
```